# Server searching for wrong PostGIS extension file version?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, extensions, pgadmin-3, postgis-2.2

Our database is hosted on a shared server, spatial queries are now failing unexpectedly returning the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory
********** Error **********
ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory
```

Querying the extentions via `pg_available_extensions` shows the extension file versions to be 2.2.5.

I'm assuming the file it should be accessing is now $libdir/postgis-2.2.5.

**How can I point the server to the correct file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the file will be postgis-2.2

We don't include the micro in the PostGIS library name.

How did you install your PostGIS?  If you did via extensions, you should be able to do:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
```